# (PostgreSQL issue) ERROR: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid

Tags: regex, postgresql

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT users_email_check 
    CHECK ( email ~ '\\A(?i-mx:[\w\.%\+\-]+)@(?i-mx:(?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.)+)(?i-mx:[a-z]{2,})\\Z' );
```

The above PostgreSQL column constraint gives:

> ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid

Note, the double backslash at Start and End of String anchors were necessary for escape because the statement is placed inside a heredoc.

Comment: Try `email ~* '^(?:[\w.%+-]+)@(?:(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)+)(?:[a-z]{2,})$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The regex had two (2) issues:

1. The `?i-mx:` were the by-product of interpolating regex inside regex in Ruby. I simply copied and pasted the resulting interpolation from Ruby. PostgreSQL didn't know how to handle them, and they're unnecessary.
2. I needed to double-up on all backslashes, like I did for Start and End of String, since the entire statement is placed inside a heredoc.

This is the correct version:

```
email ~ '\\A[\\w\\.%\\+\\-]+@(?:[a-z0-9\\-]+\\.)+(?:[a-z]{2,})\\Z'
```

Comment: You are overescaping, use `'^[\\w.%+-]+@(?:[a-z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,}$'`